nginx sub_filter not working on some uncompressed json (wordpress, elementor)
I've now spent entirely too many hours/days googling this, I've almost waterboarded chatgpt for answers, so now I need to ask for some input.
I have a nginx reverse proxy in front of a php-fpm server (wordpress). I'm using sub_filter to change some values in responses.
This is working for some json responses, but not others.
Here are relevant parts of the nginx.conf:
# Reverse proxy
server {
    ... # certificates, logging etc. removed for simplicity

    root /var/www/html;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;
    
    ...

    location / {
        gzip off;

        ... # proxy_set_header stuff removed

        proxy_set_header Accept-Encoding "";

        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8082;

        sub_filter_once off;
        sub_filter_types *;
        sub_filter "target_vlue" "replacement_value";
    }
}

# Application http
server {
    ... # listen, logging etc removed

    location ~ \.php$ {
            gzip off;
            try_files $uri =404;
            fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            include fastcgi_params;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /var/www/html$fastcgi_script_name;
            fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;

            fastcgi_pass test-wordpress:9000; #its docker
    }
}

I have the double server setup for reasons - should not be relevant here.
Notice the gzip off; and Accept-Encoding "";
In php-pfm the compression is turned off:
9dedac8fdba4:/var/www/html# php -i |grep zlib
zlib.output_compression => Off => Off
zlib.output_compression_level => -1 => -1
zlib.output_handler => no value => no value

I checked that the Content-Type header in the response is application/json; charset=utf-8 , and I've checked that application/json is part of the sub_filter types configuration.
Further debugging
The json that sub_filter does not work in is produced by Wordpress (plugin). Its big but here is a snippet:
{
  "success": true,
  "data": {
    "responses": {
      "app_site_editor_template_types": {
        "success": true,
        "code": 200,
        "data": [
          {
            "type": "header",
            ...
            "urls": {
               ...
              "thumbnail": "https://<TARGET_VALUE>/wp-content/plugins/elementor/assets/images/app/site-editor/header.svg", // <-- Here target_value is not changed by subfiler
              "EXTRA_DEBUG_TEST": "DEADBEEF"   // <--- My test, also not changed
            }
          },
          ...

As the comment says the "TARGET_VALUE" is not changed by sub_filter as hoped. If I change sub_filter to replace "DEADBEEF", thats also not working. So its not the value itself. I've edited the plugin .php to inject the extra "EXTRA_DEBUG_TEST" part of the json.
If I put a simple part of this JSON in a .php file and request that through the same server setup, then the values are replaced as expected:
{
  "status": "success",
  "message": "This is a simple JSON response",
  "items": [
    1,
    2,
    3,
    4,
    5
  ],
  "url": "https://<TARGET_VALUE>", // <-- sub_filter catches and changes this
  "url2": "https://<TARGET_VALUE>/wp-content/plugins/elementor/assets/images/app/site-editor/header.svg", // <-- sub_filter catches and changes this
}

Note: The second json is the entire debug-json used.
Anyone have any idea whats going on here?
Edit: Its not the json. I edited the plugin .php to return a really simple json object:
{
    "success": true,
    "data": {
        "responses": [ "https://<TARGET_VALUE>/wp-admin" ]
    }
}

sub_filter still not replacing the target_value.

I don't think you really add all the relevant nginx config parts. Are nginx and php-fpm different containers? Does both have access to the wordpress files via /var/www/html directory? Generally it isn't necessary, however you made it necessary using the try_files $uri =404; directive (what for?)

Ah, good questions. I ended up solving it this weekend, so I'll post the answer below. Turns out it wasn't related to your questions (so I wont edit the OP).

What a wonderful developer approach :) Still even this can be solved using nginx gunzip module as follows:
# Reverse proxy
server {
    ... # certificates, logging etc. removed for simplicity

    root /var/www/html;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;
    
    ...

    location / {
        # gzip off; <-- no need for this directive

        ... # proxy_set_header stuff removed

        proxy_set_header Accept-Encoding ""; # this one is important

        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8082;

        sub_filter_once off;
        sub_filter_types application/json;
        sub_filter "target_value" "replacement_value";
    }
}

# Application http
server {
    ... # listen, logging etc removed

    location ~ \.php$ {
        # gzip off; <-- no need for this directive
        gunzip on; # this is a key point for this config to work

        try_files $uri =404;

        # fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$; <-- this directive
        # makes no sense in "location ~ \.php$ { ... }"
        # (in opposite to something like "location ~ \.php(?:$|/) { ... }")

        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /var/www/html$fastcgi_script_name;

        # fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info; <-- this one
        # makes no sense here as well

        fastcgi_pass test-wordpress:9000; #its docker
    }
}


This answer is (more) correct than my own. @Ivan I did actually try the gunzip on; but I had it on the reverse-proxy server block and not the "application" server block. And that didn't work. I'm no nginx guru, so I don't know why, and anyway I tested setting gunzip on; in the "application" server block as your solution says, and it works like a charm. Cheers!

@MSurrow Well, you did all the debugging, without it this answer would never came out, so lets say we share the credits on this one :) I know how boring such a debugging could be sometimes...

The answer to your question - I don't know why - is actually quite simple. For the gunzip directive to take effect on compressed responses, a server block must receive a request without the gzip method listed in the Accept-Encoding HTTP  header. Your reverse proxy server receives the request from the browser, which, of course, includes an Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, ... header, and there’s little you can do about that. However, you can remove this header when proxying the request to your application server, thereby triggering the gunzip directive within that server block.

they could have put that in the documentation (https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_gunzip_module.html).. I mean, I see the “ for clients that do not support “gzip” encoding method.” and after reading your comment about the request accept-encoding header, I get that that’s how it can/should be understood, but a little too implicit for my taste :-)

Okay, so I ended up finding the issue. Just in case someone in the future has the same problem, I'll post the solution here.
The Wordpress plugin is Elementor and Elementor-pro. My issue was specifically related to the Theme Editor feature. Its a pro feature and it calls admin-ajax.php for som editor config values. The action triggered is:
$ajax->register_ajax_action( 'app_site_editor_template_types', [ $this, 'get_template_types' ] );

The implementation looks ok. But the culpit is in Elementor core, specifally in elementor/core/common/modules/ajax/module.php where we have this gem:
private function send_success() {
    
// things left out

if ( function_exists( 'gzencode' ) ) {
    $response = gzencode( $json );

    header( 'Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8' );
    header( 'Content-Encoding: gzip' );
    header( 'Content-Length: ' . strlen( $response ) );

    echo $response; // phpcs:ignore WordPress.Security.EscapeOutput.OutputNotEscaped
} else {
    echo $json; // phpcs:ignore WordPress.Security.EscapeOutput.OutputNotEscaped
}

wp_die( '', '', [ 'response' => null ] );
}

This function wraps the call to admin-ajax.php. As we can see it happily disregards any HTTP headers and PHP config, and compresses the output JSON regardless. Which is why none of the nginx or php config changes had any effect.
